In framer motion how can i handle the overflow in motion.div
I am trying to create a parallax card effect for a website but while making the cards responsive I have been stuck on this that the contents of the card overflow the given height which cuts out the content or covers up the previous content.To resolve that i tried overflow-scroll in the motion.div and also tried by putting the content in another div with full height and width and gave overflow scroll it but the scroll is not working in those cases. I am making this in the next.js using framer-motion,tailwind css and lenis. You can find the code i used below.
Animation cards.
'

use client';
    import { motion, useScroll, useTransform, MotionValue } from "framer-motion";
    import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
    import Lenis from 'lenis';
    import EginitionEvents from "../EgnitionEvents";

// Defining the type for scrollYProgress
interface SectionProps {
  scrollYProgress: MotionValue<number>;
}

export default function EgnitionCardsAnimation() {
  const container = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const { scrollYProgress } = useScroll({
    target: container,
    offset: ["start start", "end end"]
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const lenis = new Lenis();

    function raf(time: number) {
      lenis.raf(time);
      requestAnimationFrame(raf);
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(raf);
  }, []);

  return (
    <main ref={container} className="relative h-[200vh]">
      <Section1 scrollYProgress={scrollYProgress} />
      <Section2 scrollYProgress={scrollYProgress} />
    </main>
  );
}

const Section1: React.FC<SectionProps> = ({ scrollYProgress }) => {
  const scale = useTransform(scrollYProgress, [0, 1], [1, 0.8]);
  const rotate = useTransform(scrollYProgress, [0, 1], [0, 0]);

  return (
    <motion.div
      style={{ scale, rotate }}
      className="sticky top-0 h-screen bg-[#C72626] text-[3.5vw] flex flex-col items-center justify-center text-white pb-[10vh]"
    >
      <p>Section 1 - Scroll Perspective</p>
      <p>Content for section 1.</p>
    </motion.div>
  );
};

const Section2: React.FC<SectionProps> = ({ scrollYProgress }) => {
    const scale = useTransform(scrollYProgress, [0, 1], [0.8, 1]);
    const rotate = useTransform(scrollYProgress, [0, 1], [0, 0])

  return (
    <motion.div
      style={{ scale, rotate }}
      className="sticky top-[100vh] h-screen bg-[#000] flex flex-col items-center justify-center pt-[10vh] overflow-hidden"
    >
      <EginitionEvents/>
    </motion.div>
  );
};

Cards content
// components/CardComponent.tsx
import React from "react";
import styles from "./CardComponent.module.scss";
import Image from "next/image";

type CardProps = {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  imageSrc: string;
};

const EventCards: React.FC = () => {
  const cards: CardProps[] = [
    {
      title: "Design",
      description:
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur iure excepturi recusandae voluptates, praesentium illo aperiam voluptatum temporibus.",
      imageSrc: "/images/1.jpg",
    },
    {
      title: "Development",
      description:
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur iure excepturi recusandae voluptates, praesentium illo aperiam voluptatum temporibus.",
      imageSrc: "/images/1.jpg",
    },
    {
      title: "Marketing",
      description:
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur iure excepturi recusandae voluptates, praesentium illo aperiam voluptatum temporibus.",
      imageSrc: "/images/1.jpg",
    },
    {
      title: "Research",
      description:
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur iure excepturi recusandae voluptates, praesentium illo aperiam voluptatum temporibus.",
      imageSrc: "/images/3.jpg",
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div className={`${styles.container} container flex flex-wrap justify-between mx-auto w-[90vw]`}>
      {cards.map((card, index) => (
        <div
          key={index}
          className={`${styles.card} relative flex bg-white h-64 w-full sm:w-full md:w-[45%] lg:w-[45%] m-4`}
        >
          <div
            className={`${styles.imgbox} absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full bg-gray-800 flex justify-center items-center overflow-hidden`}
            data-text={card.title}
          >
            <Image
              src={card.imageSrc}
              alt={`Image of ${card.title}`}
              width={100}  // Define width here
              height={100} // Define height here
              className="transition-all duration-500 max-w-[100px]"
            />
          </div>
          <div className={`${styles.detail} absolute right-0 w-[calc(100%-75px)] h-full p-4 flex flex-col justify-center items-start`}>
            <h3 className="mb-2 text-lg font-bold">{card.title}</h3>
            <p className="text-sm mb-4">{card.description}</p>
            <a
              href="#"
              className="bg-gray-800 text-white px-4 py-2 text-sm no-underline"
            >
              Read more...
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default EventCards;

Cards styling using scss and css
.contain {
    margin: 20px 0;
  }
  
  .card {
    position: relative;
    height: 250px;
    display: flex;
    margin: 30px 0;
  
    &:hover .imgbox {
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      left: -75px;
      top: calc(50% - 75px);
      background-color: #ff0257;
      transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }
  
    &:hover .imgbox img {
      max-width: 75px;
      transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }
  }
  
  .imgbox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 3;
  
    &::before {
      content: attr(data-text);
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 6em;
      color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
      font-weight: 700;
    }
  }
  
  .detail {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 20px;
  }
  
  @media (max-width:992px){
    .container{
        width: 100%;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;  
    }
    .container .card{
        width: 400px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 500px){
    .container .card{
        max-width: 300px;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: auto;
    }
    .container .card .imgbox{
        position: relative;
    }
    .container .card .imgbox,
    .container .card:hover .imgbox{
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
    .container .card .imgbox img,
    .container .card:hover .imgbox img{
        max-width: 100px;
    }
    .container .card .detail{
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .container .card .imgbox::before{
        content: attr(data-text);
        font-size: 5em;
    }
}

